# How to determine the order in which vector 3D shapes ought to be drawn

Tags: java, algorithm, 3d, geometry, polygons

I found a question similar to mine (couldn't link it as I need 10 reputation to post more than two links), however it was confusing to me as I am only a beginner in Java.

So far, I've made a program that can display a three dimensional map plane and draw three dimensional prisms onto it that are rotatable across two axises using trigonometry and the `g.fillPolygon` method, however I can't figure out an algorithm to determine what order each shape should be drawn in to prevent some shapes drawing on top of others where they shouldn't be.

[image: An example of objects being drawn in the wrong order]

<sup>An example of objects being drawn in the wrong order</sup>

My current algorithm iterates from left to right diagonally, starting at the point of the map farthest away from the viewer's perspective, and checks to see if any of the shapes being drawn have a back corner that corresponds with the given point.

But this has a few issues, as any iteration that holds two or more shapes can often lead to drawing issues like the one in the example at the beginning of the post.

[image: How my algorithm works, and example of when it fails]

<sup>How my algorithm works, and example of when it fails</sup>

I'm fairly new to coding and using math this way, so I'd love for this concept to be explained relatively simply. Also, if there's anything I've missed in my explanation, I recorded a short demo of my program [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MqCuiV8ooVg&feature=youtu.be) -- hopefully that will help clear up anything I missed.

UPDATE: I (think) I figured it out. For all shapes drawn on the same iterative line, I order them based on whether the shape to the left has a point to the right of the farthest point that has a greater x/y value (depending on which way the map is oriented) than the farthest point of the shape to its right.

Comment: You might be looking for [Painter's algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Painter%27s_algorithm); however, depending upon how you are rendering them, you might alternatively be able to use [Z-Buffering](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Z-buffering).

Comment: @Andy Turner What I am doing currently is pretty similar to the Painter's algorithm, from what I can tell. I'm drawing from back to front, using the farthest corner of each object's position to determine the order that they are drawn in. However, I think the area where my algorithm fails (as shown in the picture) would qualify as "overlapping polygon," so it doesn't work entirely in certain cases. As for Z-Buffering, that looks well above my abilities as far as I can tell. I feel that altering my algorithm to function correctly under the circumstances it fails is the best route, but maybe not.

Comment: You description is far too broad to give much help, but the thing which caught my eye was the "have a back corner". Have you tried the front corner?

Comment: @Andy Turner Yes, I have tried checking using the front point, and it didn't work. I wasn't sure how to best describe the algorithm. Maybe [this](http://imgur.com/TtvwYC4) picture will describe it a bit better? The number on the dots signify the order that they are checked to see if they contain a shape, and red dots signify "hits" where a shape's back corner lies within it. I know this is pretty inefficient, but it's a good starting point, and later on I can make an algorithm that sorts the order that objects are drawn by only checking their position, rather than checking each possible slot.

Comment: @Andy Turner My only hunch is that, for each line that is iterated through on the grid, if there is more than one shape found, I need to check to see if the point to the left and right of the farthest back point are displayed over any other shapes that were found on that line. However, I'm not sure how I can check this. Each shape has an X and Y position on the grid, and a length, width, (and height, although that shouldn't matter for this I think), and I have been using these to determine the point that is farthest away for each object for comparison, if that helps.

Answer (score 0):

If you have two shapes, you can find out which one should be drawn first by finding the middle of the region where they overlap on the screen and sampling the distance to the camera there (doesn't have to be exactly the middle, can be just a point sufficiently different from the interval ends). This should be reliable for convex 2D shapes (which seems to be the ones you are using). When sorting the full list, note that if any two shapes don't overlap, the relation between them is "undefined" and so none of the transitivity rules implied by sorting algorithms apply, so you'll probably have to find "islands" of overlapping shapes and sort them based on existing overlaps only.